# Changing date format while insertion in PLSQL

Tags: date, datetime, plsql

I am writing a PLSQL script where I am fetching few columns from one table and inserting it into another. One of those columns is a date column. I want to change the date format from `dd-mmm-yy` to `yyyy-mm-dd` `hh:mm:ss`

e.g. if the date in table1 is `01-DEC-16`, I want it to get inserted in table2 as `2016-12-01 00:00:00` or whatever the default time is.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You need to first fix the source data ie. this  `01-DEC-16` has to be changed to `01-DEC-2016` and then use it as `select to_char(to_date('01-DEC-2016','DD-MON-YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MM:SS') from dual`

Comment: Dates have no format. Their representation as a string does. If the source and target fields *are* dates, instead of character fields that store something that looks like a date, you don't have to change anything. A simple `INSERT INTO (datefield1) SELECT thatOtherDateField from TheOthertable` would be enough

Comment: but the date format in table1 is dd-mon-yy. I want to change it to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: What are the datatypes of the two columns containing dates? If they are actual Oracle `date` columns (not character strings) then it would be helpful to explain what you mean by them having a format.

Comment: @AbidMajgaonkar : It is a common mistake to assume that Oracle stores date column values in a particular format. Dates are simply stored as date irrespective of what the user sees. The format you see on the screen depends on the NLS session parameters. So if your source is a char field  and destination is Date , use to_date with proper format. use to_char if vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can do select `to_char`

```
select to_char(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from table;
```

Comment: my current script is something like this: DECLARE
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT created, column1 FROM table1;
BEGIN
FOR i IN C1 LOOP
IF (i.column1 = 'value1' OR i.column1 = 'value2') THEN

INSERT INTO table2(CREATEDDATE, column2_name) VALUES (i.created, 'abc');

ELSE
INSERT INTO table2(CREATEDDATE, column2_name) VALUES (i.created, 'xyz');

COMMIT;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END; Sorry for the messy look!

Comment: @AbidMajgaonkar If your `created` from table1 is of `date` datatype then it would have timestamp component. No need to do anything. You can use your script and while seleting the data you can use what is shown above. Also `commit` has to be outside the `Loop` else it would only `commit` when `ELSE` condition is satisfied

Comment: If I use the select statement as you have shown, how will I call it in my insert statement?

Comment: Also, using to_char gives following error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string ORA-06512: at line 10